# Visual Studio 2012 ALT+Number Sendkeys Doesn't Work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sendkeys

Hello I am making a vs2012 project where when the timer reaches 10 seconds the program will send ALT+2. the F1 alone worked with sendkeys but wont work with ALT TAB or ALT+Number. Here are some codes i tried so far that doesn't work.

```
    If mintCount = 16 Then SendKeys.Send("%2")
    If mintCount = 16 Then SendKeys.Send("%(2)")
    If mintCount = 16 Then SendKeys.Send("(%2)")
    If mintCount = 16 Then SendKeys.Send("%{2}")
    If mintCount = 16 Then SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}")
```

any suggestion or tip would be appreciated thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize my `InputHelper` class. It P/Invokes the native [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function of the WinAPI. It is more flexible than `SendKeys` and also supports a wider set of keys!

> **EDIT (2019-09-20)**
>
> `InputHelper` has since long been moved to its own library. The answer has been updated to reflect this change.
>
> **Download InputHelper from GitHub:**
>   https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

**Usage:**

```
InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.Alt, True) 'True = Hold ALT key down.
InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.D2) 'Press "2".
InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.Alt, False) 'False = Release ALT key.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I am still new to Vb programming where should i put or how do i create the InputHelper.vb code? It gives me error when i paste it to Form1.vb. I think i have to create a separate vb file and call the usage code to form1.vb but i am confused. please help

Comment: @Snoopy : Yes it's a separate file (hence the `.vb` extension). If you're using Visual Studio right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and go to `Add > New Item...`, _**OR**_ press `CTRL + SHIFT + A` on the keyboard. In the window that opens select `Class` and give it the name `InputHelper.vb`, then just remove the auto-generated code in it and replace it with my code.

Answer (score -1):

use keyboard.sendkeys instead:

My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("%{TAB}", True)

this should send alt tab to the active window and the boolean specifies whether to pause the application till the keystrokes have been processed or not.

Comment: FYI `SendKeys` and `Keyboard.SendKeys` are essentially the same.

Comment: im wondering though, i tried this code and it does exactly what the question was. Any Idea what might cause Problems for him?

Comment: Don't know, but he isn't the first... It is very rare, but `SendKeys` doesn't seem to work on some computers.

Comment: Tip: To notify someone when you write a comment (_**unless**_ you write it on that person's question or answer) write `@username` somewhere in the text. `username` is the person's user name without spaces. For instance: @VisualVincent.

Comment: Also, when writing code in a comment you can escape it by surrounding it with backticks ( \` ) like so: `\`code here\``. For example: `TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"`. -- For more info see the [**formatting and markdown help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).